# bootstrap 2 navbar break point change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla3.0

I am building a joomla template using built in bootstrap version 2.3.2. The problem is i have long navbar when it comes on tablets, it divide in two lines i would like to have it collapse at 1200px. I am using following code for navigation.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Add JavaScript Frameworks
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');

// Load optional rtl Bootstrap css and Bootstrap bugfixes
JHtmlBootstrap::loadCss($includeMaincss = true);

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<jdoc:include type="head" />
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/media/jui/js/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
<link href="templates/test/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="logo" class="span12"><a href="home.html"><img src="templates/test/images/logo.png" alt="Home - Freeterm Limited, London"></a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <nav class="span12 navbar">
     <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
     <div class="nav-collapse collapse"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav" style="none" /></div>
     </div>
  </nav>
</div></div>
```

The CSS is as below:

```
.navbar {
    margin: 0px;
}

.navbar-inner {
  min-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  background-color: #363f45;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #363f45, #363f45);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#363f45), to(#363f45));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #363f45, #363f45);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #363f45, #363f45);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #363f45, #363f45);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff363f45', endColorstr='#ff363f45', GradientType=0);
  border: 0px solid #d4d4d4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
}

/* ----- Main Menu Styling ----- */

.navbar .nav > li > a {
  font-family: 'helvetica', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  border-left: 1px solid #21262b;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #8dbf41;
}
.navbar .nav > .active > a,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #8dbf41;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar .nav li.item-101 a {
    border-left: none;
}

/*----- Drop Menu -----*/

nav .nav-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 0px 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #363f45;
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    border: 0px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    *border-right-width: 0px;
    *border-bottom-width: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 0 px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
nav .nav-child.pull-right {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
nav .nav-child .divider {
    *width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 8px 1px;
    *margin: -5px 0 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
nav .nav-child a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'helvetica', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
nav .nav > li {
    position: relative;
}
nav .nav > li:hover > .nav-child,
nav .nav > li > a:focus + .nav-child {
    display: block;
}

nav .nav-child li > a:hover,
nav .nav-child li > a:focus,
nav .nav-child:hover > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #8dbf41;
}

/*----- Nav Bar Button -----*/

.navbar .btn-navbar {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-color: #363f45;
  *background-color: #363f45;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #363f45, #363f45);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#363f45), to(#363f45));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #363f45, #363f45);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #363f45, #363f45);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #363f45, #363f45);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #363f45 #363f45 #363f45;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff363f45', endColorstr='#ff363f45', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
          box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 0 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.navbar .btn-navbar:hover,
.navbar .btn-navbar:focus,
.navbar .btn-navbar:active,
.navbar .btn-navbar.active,
.navbar .btn-navbar.disabled,
.navbar .btn-navbar[disabled] {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #363f45;
  *background-color: #363f45;
}
```

Comment: At present the navbar collapses at 768px.

Answer (score 1):

> just add this in your css file

```html
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .navbar-header {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: #222 !important;
    border-color: transparent;
    padding:0px !important;
}
.nav > li {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative;
}
.navbar-left, .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
}
.navbar-nav > li.navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
}
.navbar{
 
 min-height:50px;
 position:relative;
}
  .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
      display: block !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
      top: 0;
      border-width: 0 0 1px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
      display: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin-top: 7.5px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
      float: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .collapse.in{
      display:block !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: this messed up the menu more the drop down sub menus keep showing and the collapse is still happening at 768px. See the image. [link](http://gcmsonline.net/Untitled-2.png)

Comment: thank you i have found a solution the collapse width is defined in variables.less it has to be changed there and then recompiled.